# Django Forms, set an initial value to request.user

Tags: python, django-forms

Is there some way to make the following possible, or should it be done elsewhere?

```
class JobRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    supervisor = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset    = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Supervisors'), 
        widget      = forms.RadioSelect,
        initial     = request.user # is there some way to make this possible?
    )    
    class Meta:
        model = JobRecord
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to handle this in your view function.  Since your view function must create the initial form, and your view function knows the user.

```
form = JobRecordForm( {'supervisor':request.user} )
```

This will trigger validation of this input, BTW, so you can't provide hint values this way.

Answer (score 30):

If you do this in your view.py instead:

```
form = JobRecordForm( initial={'supervisor':request.user} )
```

Then you won't trigger the validation.

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

Answer (score 6):

An Another solution with Middleware and save rewriting :
With middleware solution You can call "request" everywhere.

---

""" Middleware """

```
    # coding: utf-8 
from django.utils.thread_support import currentThread 
_requests = {}

def get_request():
    return _requests[currentThread()]

class GlobalRequestMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):  
        _requests[currentThread()] = request
```

---

""" save Rewrinting """

```
class Production(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "%(class)s_creator")
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    modification_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def save(self, force_insert = False, force_update = False):

        self.creator = get_request().user
        super(Production, self).save(force_insert = force_insert, force_update = force_update)
        return
```

Comment: do I have to import anything to use this `get_request()` method?

Comment: what is stored in `_request[currentThread()]`? is it a reference to the `request` object or the value of it? what I really want to know is: Would any later change done (by other middleware, for instance) be reflected on it? in case not, wouldn't it be better to store it in the `process_view()` method, in the middleware? Thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 5):

For a complete answer, here's the CBV solution:

```
class MyFormView(TemplateView, FormMixin):
    def get_initial(self):
        self.initial.update({'your_field': self.request.user})
        return super(MyFormView, self).get_initial()
```