# how to use the GlobalRequestMiddleware strategy?

Tags: django

I'm trying to use the GlobalRequestMiddleware strategy as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653735/django-forms-set-an-initial-value-to-request-user).  I have implemented the middleware exactly as written, and when I want to use it, I have

```
from myapp.middeware.GlobalRequestMiddleware import get_request
request = get_request()
```

but get_request throws a KeyError.  I have a feeling that the problem has something to do with how I'm importing get_request, as the _requests variable has two different ids in process_request and in get_request.  (If I don't put the "import" statement in, python complains that "get_request is not defined")

Can someone clear up my confusion?

Comment: Shouldn't you be importing with `from myapp.middleware import get_request`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually installed the middleware in settings.py?